# New Profile banner lacks punctuation at the end of sentences

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

[Meta profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) got a big blue banner. It's neat, but the long sentences describing various features should probably end with a full stop.

[image: profile]

Comment: Lol, there should always be some punctuation or grammar error, shouldn't there?

Comment: Punctuation is noise

Comment: Need to get rid of all those noisy capital letters too.

Comment: And of commas in the middle of those sentences.

Comment: I will not support this unless `Hammer Time` comes after every full stop.

Comment: The first commas on the first and third blurbs are also unnecessary.

Comment: @AstroCB I think they're fine. Breaks up the flow from one sentence component to another. I think such things do carry a lot of personal preference, and is down to writing styles :)

Comment: @James Normally I'm in favor of that, but here, they're just distracting and make the descriptions sound jumpy and tacky, in my opinion. It contradicts the current Stack Exchange writing style that I've seen around the sites.

Comment: @AstroCB Taking the first one as an example, there are a lot of comma separated items at the end, and segregating the first part from the second part that contains separated items seems more logical. Again, personal choice I suppose.

Comment: @AstroCB I suppose it's the new SE style, a hallmark of the _People Helped_ era of the network's lifecycle.

Comment: The commas are serial or Oxford commas: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma

Comment: @Oded what exactly is completed? Just added dots? :)

Comment: @Sha - well, yes... and will be there in the next build.

Answer (score 4):

These sound very awkward and hastily put-together.

Proposed replacements:

> The [new profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile) shows off your most helpful posts and lets users follow you on Twitter, GitHub, Stack Overflow Careers, or any other site.
>
> The new [activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) tracks your contributions, including the number of times someone searching for help found your posts here.
>
> Whether you're brand new or have helped millions already, the [activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity)'s "next privilege" and "next badge" bars can encourage you to take the next step.

In context:

[image: The banner]

(I'll admit that that last one may be a bit too long.)

Comment: ...and don't end a block with an orphaned word...

Comment: @Werner I assumed that's something they'd fix design-wise on their side if they decided to use this wording.

Comment: "*These sound very awkward and hastily put-together*" I'm not entirely sure that is a fair statement to make. I think you are confusing "mistake" with "personal preference".

Comment: @James The only reason I say that is because they don't sound (or look) like anything else I've seen around SE.

Comment: @AstroCB Such as?

Comment: @James Look at the blurbs around the site and the articles in the Help Center – these don't sound anything like those.

Comment: The Help Center is different, it is not a banner. The HC has multiple vertical sentences and paragraphs on the same column, so they need full stops. The banner has 3 columns with only one block of text in each column (only one sentence actually) and each item's text is clearly separated from the others. I don't believe in this case it's "necessary", and refer back to my answer of "personal preference" and "consistency". "Banner" vs "page of text" is apples and oranges.

Comment: @James "Consistency" *is* the key here. You imply from "personal preference" that this is a matter of style, which it is. So then the question is – whose style? If you want consistency, you should use the same writing style throughout the network pages and prompts. These prompts use numerous capital letters and excessive commas, both of which go against the consistent norm seen on other other similar pieces of text throughout the site.

Comment: A banner with colours and images and only 3 columns with a single sentence on each column is a completely different thing to the help center page with no colours or images, many paragraphs and descriptions and a page full of text. Should the HC have a blue background? Or images? Or separated into 3 columns because the banner is? Or should consistency only extend to *sentences of text*? I agree consistency should remain throughout the site, not just within a single part of it, but a banner is not a page of text.

Comment: @James We're talking about writing style consistency here – not design. I'm not trying to attack yours or anyone else's opinion; I'm just giving mine.

Comment: I'm not talking about design either. It is perfectly acceptable for writing style to change between two completely different things. Of course throughout the help center and tour page it should all look and read the same, in a similar style etc. But this is not about a page full of paragraphs and text. It's a banner. Are there any other banners on Stack? If yes, then this one should be consistent with that one. Otherwise, if this is the only banner on the whole of MSE, then they can do what they want

Comment: I wasn't *attacking* your opinion, nor did I feel you were "attacking" mine. We were just *debating*, chewin' the fat  ;)

Answer (score -1):

> but the long sentences describing various features should probably end
>   with a full stop

Personally I prefer them without full stops/periods in a banner like that, as it's obvious where the block of text for one column or single feature ends.

Full stops/periods are more for when you need vertical separation, i.e. like your question, my answer, etc. Whereas horizontal blocks like in the banner don't really need them.

That said, I don't think either way is grammatically *incorrect* or required, it's more personal writing style and choice, the main thing is consistency.